# Decrypting tar archives with gpg -d, the -d flag does not work

Tags: encryption, gnupg, tar, archiving

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04.2 lts.

I am creating a tar archive from the dir noup1, that contains files and subfolders, with `tar cf no1.tar noup1`

Encrypt it with `gpg -c no1.tar`. So now I have a `no1.tar.gpg` archive.

If I try to decrypt it with `gpg -d no1.tar.gpg`, I get a lot of squiggly characters in the terminal and it does not work.

If I just use `gpg no1.tar.gpg`, without the `-d` flag, I get an output saying "no command was given. Trying to guess ..."

`gpg: WARNING:  Kein Kommando angegeben.  Versuche zu raten was gemeint ist ...`
`gpg: AES256 verschlüsselte Daten`
`gpg: Verschlüsselt mit einer Passphrase`

and the archive is now unencrypted. So this works! **But how and why**?

On the other hand if I use the `-d` flag and pipe the result into tar it succeeds!

`gpg -d no1.tar.gpg | tar xf -`

[How to create compressed encrypted archives with tar and gpg](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-compressed-encrypted-archives-with-tar-and-gpg)

**So I am wondering:**

What is the "**guessed command**" that was executed?

Why does the `-d` flag not work, but it does if piped into tar, even though all relevant tutorials instruct to decrypt a tar archive using `gpg -d <archive-name>` and not `gpg <archive-name>`?

Is it possible I am missing some packages or something is wrong with my gpg configuration?

Answer (score 0):

per the [manpages](http://manpages.org/gpg) for gpg,

> -d
>
> Decrypt the file given on the command line (or STDIN if no file is specified) and write it to STDOUT (or the file specified with
> --output). If the decrypted file is signed, the signature is also verified. This command differs from the default operation, as it never
> writes to the filename which is included in the file and it rejects
> files which don't begin with an encrypted message.

so -d was working fine, but it was decrypting the file to the STDOUT, which is why you saw a bunch of junk output. that is the encoded data for your .tar file, so its no surprise its gibberish.

if you want it to decrypt to a file instead of your shell output stream, use `--output <filename>` or redirect output to a file.

I believe (I can't read German) that when you ran the command on the file, I assume it ran the equivalent of

`gpg -d no1.tar.gpg --output no1.tar`

Comment: `gpg -d no1.tar.gpg --output no1.tar` has the following output on my system: `gpg: Note: '--output' is not considered an option
usage: gpg [options] --decrypt [filename]`

Comment: Options have to be listed before commands: `gpg --output no1.tar -d no1.tar.gpg`